# Function to read json data and a json path to return a tuple or list

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

This is probably a newbie question.

But I am trying to create a function (or find a library that has one) to return a tuple or a list when I pass a json data and jsonPath to it; something like this:

```
Tup1 = Extract(json_data,json_path) 
List1 = Extract(json_data,json_path)
```

so basically turning something like this:

```
{
    "name"="john",
    "age"=25
}
```

to

```
Tup1 = ('john',25)
```

OR

```
List1 = ['john',25]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with minimal coding ?

Comment: What is the json path for? Are you going to save it later?

Comment: And the same function wouldn't return two different type just because you changed the variable name

Comment: @abccd answers:
1- I create the json_path string based on what i know about the schema of json_data, which I can change later the schema changes
2- I don't need to return both types, either one of them works for me

Comment: One more question: is you json data a dict parsed by the `json` module? Or not yet and just raw string?

Comment: @abccd can be, I can parse with json module before sending it to the fucntion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsonpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath) package is a small library that I used to extract an element using its jsonpath address and create a function that gets json data and a list of jsonpath elements and returns the corresponding values for each element from json data as a tuple:

Obviously you can extend this according to your own requirements

```
from jsonpath import jsonpath

def json2tuple(json_data,jsonpaths_list):
    return_data = []

    for path in jsonpaths_list :
        return_data.append(jsonpath(json_data,path)[0])

    return(tuple(return_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is that you can to use a *simple list comprehension* to join all the values into a list from the json data after it has been parsed. To handle the parsing, just use `json.load` to load a file or `json.loads` to load from a string.

This will return as a list:

```
import json
def Extract(json_data,json_path):
    json_data = json.load(json_path) # parse the data from json_path, if it's already parsed, skip this line
    return [val for val in json_data.values()] # add tuple() around it if you want tuple instead

List1 = Extract(json_data,json_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

`{
    "name"="john",
    "age"=25
}`

is not a correct syntax for a json data, you need to replace `=` with `:`

`{
    "name":"john",
    "age":25
}`

One of the ways to do is :

```
import json

#assuming json_data contains valid data
def Extract(json_data, json_path, format="list"):
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_data)
        if format == "list":
            reutrn data.values()
        elif format == "tuple":
            reutrn tuple(data.values())
    except ValueError as e:
        print "error in parsing json_data", e

#assuming json_path contains valid data     
def Extract(json_data, json_path, format="list"):
    try:
        data = json.load(json_path)
        if format == "list":
            reutrn data.values()
        elif format == "tuple":
            reutrn tuple(data.values())
    except ValueError as e:
        print "error in parsing json_data", e       
    except IOError as e:
        print "error in opening json_path", e
```